# Any way or extension for keeping the opened files in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

As in Notepad++ or Sublime text, the last opened file are retained if we close and open the editor again. So is there any way to do it in VS Code (Visual Studio Code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest insider version (1.11.0 insider) support that. It remembers all opened files, saved or not, when closing and re-load them when opening.

You need a workspace open to enable this feature (see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/207))

Answer (score 0):

// Controls if opened editors should show in tabs or not.
  "workbench.editor.showTabs": true,

// Controls how folders are being reopened after a restart. Select 'none' to never reopen a folder, 'one' to reopen the last folder you worked on or 'all' to reopen all folders of your last session.
  "window.reopenFolders": "one",

Check to see how you have these set in your preferences, particularly 
"window.reopenFolders"  isn't none.

Comment: It might work for folders but its not working for opened files.